# Add property to object only if value is defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Is there a better way to add a property to an object only if the value is defined :

```
const destination = {};
const value = getValue();

if (_(value).isObject()) { // In this case, I only want an object
    destination.value = value;
}
```

In this case, the `destination.value` property exists only if `value` has a value. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: `if (value)` generally, when you know that value will not be a falsey value that you want to keep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also do the Object-test with `Object(value) === value` and perform the conditional assignment with `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(destination, Object(value) === value && { value });
```

Whether this is "better" is debatable. Pick what you like most and best suits your expectations.

Answer (score 84):

With ES6, I like to do conditional spreading:

```
const value = getValue()
const destination = {
  ...(value ? { value } : {})
}
```

And you can do whatever boolean check you need in the ternary. In your case, checking to see if `value` is an object.

Comment: This is a bit different setup than the OP had, where `destination` already existed as a `const` before the `getValue()` function was called.

Comment: The spread syntax is not available for Objects in ES6. It is still a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread).

Comment: Good catch, Patrick! It's officially in stage 4 now so this should be good to go.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 37):

**Update**

Here is a better ES6 way,

```
const destination = {};
const value = getValue();
destination = {
    ...destination, 
    ...(value && { value }),
}
```

Here the assumption is you want to make a key with the name `value` itself.

**Another approach**

just do like this,

```
const destination = {};
const value = getValue();

value && (destination.value = value); // here is the one liner way
```

This will make sure that the *value* attribute is getting create only if *value* is defined

Answer (score 4):

A similar solution to the top-voted answer but slightly shorter --

```
const value = getValue()
const destination = {
    ...(value && { value }),
}
```

This will be valuable if you are conditionally overwriting many properties. Just now I had to do --

```
const destination = {
    ...(newAddress.givenName && { firstName: newAddress.givenName }),
    ...(newAddress.familyName && { lastName: newAddress.familyName }),
    ...(newAddress.organizationName && { company: newAddress.organizationName }),
    ...(newAddress.phone && { phoneNumber: newAddress.phone }),
    ...(newAddress.streetAddress && { address1: newAddress.streetAddress }),
    ...(newAddress.streetAddress2 && { address2: newAddress.streetAddress2 }),
    ...(newAddress.city && { city: newAddress.city }),
    ...(newAddress.region && { state: newAddress.region }),
    ...(newAddress.country && { country: newAddress.country }),
    ...(newAddress.postalCode && { zip: newAddress.postalCode }),
}

const result = {
    ...defaultAddress,
    ...destinationAddress
}
```

Where any of the `newAddress` can be `undefined` or `null`, making it extra safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof value != 'undefined')
```

Unless you want to exclude null also (null is an object in javascript). In that case:

```
if(typeof value != 'undefined' && value !=null)
```

Comment: Thats a normal comparision between an object and if is null or undefined. The question was to add this value as a property inside an object.

Comment: @SebastianPaduano my thinking was, that adding the value would go into the body of the IF statement - but you are right, I did not make that explicit.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way could be to put values that you want to add in an array and use `filter` and `forEach` (or `reduce`) to add it to the `destination` object.

```
const destination = {}
const propsToAdd = [{ key: 'value', value: getValue() }]

propsToAdd
 .filter(data => _.isObject(data.value))
 .forEach(data => destination[data.key] = data.value);
```

That way you can also add a function to the object that you can use in the `filter` to validate other types rather than only objects.